# Google mail- ad responses

Tags: gmail

We are a recruitment business, and we use google mail.

All our job ad responses are emailed to our Google Mail account.

We keep getting duplicate ad responses from the same person, because a customer might apply one day, then a few days later forget they have applied and apply again.

Is there anyway that we can group all emails from one sender together?

I know about the conversation view, but usually that only groups emails together when I have replied to a customer's email. We have enabled conversation view, but we still get new emails from the same person essentially applying again.

We don't need all these duplicate emails.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Gmail groups conversations based on the subject line.

What you're looking for can't be done in Gmail straight-up. You'll either need to use a third-party tool or force your ad responses to use the same subject line for each person.

Gmail is an email system. It sounds to me that you need a CRM system.